# EpubCheck in Calibre gives errors with epub:type and aside

Tags: epub, calibre, epubcheck, footnotes

[image]I get these two errors:

ERROR(RSC-005): Error while parsing file 'attribute "epub:type" not allowed here;

ERROR(RSC-005): Error while parsing file 'element "aside" not allowed anywhere;

How can I remove them? I want to use pop-up footnotes with epub3.

Regards Dan

Comment: Welcome to ebooks-SE. We try to keep thanks to a minimum as it is overhead for most readers. You should **never use an answer for thanking, or even for discussing**. For that purpose, you can use comments, or possibly editing a previous post. Comments require minimum reputation of 50, but there is an exception when you authored the question, or if you wrote the commented answer. Hence your thanks will be deleted (You cannot do it yourself ... but do not worry). See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead

Answer (score 1):

`epub:type` attributes can only be used in epub**3** books. You'll need to select **Polish books > Upgrade book internals** to convert your epub2 book to an epub3 book.

Comment: Thank you Nemo, this solution worked fine.

Comment: Under the updated version, (mine is version 6.8.0 now), I go to: Tools > Upgrade book internals

Answer (score 0):

A quick fix on top of "**Tools > Upgrade book internals**" is to add the following HTML attribute for html files that uses "epub:type"

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" **xmlns:epub="http://www.idpf.org/2007/ops"**>

Do take note that after you did the "**Upgrade book internals**" once, your subsequent HTML files will not have the **xmlns:epub** attribute. Running "**Upgrade book internals**" again will still give you the error as the **xmlns:epub** attribute is not added into the new HTML file. Hence, it is good to paste manually.